# Why is this not saving into my database? Trying to save into two tables

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to save a question that has options, those options are saved into another table than the question itself.

This is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = new SurveyQuestion;
    $preg->question = $request->question;
    $preg->survey_section_id = $request->survey_section_id;
    $preg->response_type_id = $request->response_type_id;
    $preg->optional = $request->optional;
    $preg->save();

    if ($request->get('questionOptions')) {
        $options = [];
        $preg_id = $preg->id;

        foreach ($request->get('questionOptions') as $item) {
            $option = $item['option'];
            if (isset($survey_question_id, $option)) {
                $options[] = [
                  "survey_question_id" => $preg_id,
                  "option" => $option
                ];
            }
        }
        if (count($options)) {
            SurveyQuestionOption::insert($options);
        }
    }

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

These are the tables

```
Schema::create('survey_questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('question');
    $table->integer('survey_section_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('response_type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('optional');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('survey_section_id')->references('id')->on('survey_sections');
    $table->foreign('response_type_id')->references('id')->on('response_types');
});

Schema::create('survey_question_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('option');
    $table->integer('survey_question_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('survey_question_id')->references('id')->on('survey_questions');
});
```

The relationships go like this

```
SurveyQuestion         ->   hasMany     ->   SurveyQuestionOption
SurveyQuestionOption   ->   belongsTo   ->   SurveyQuestion
```

In my vue I have `questionOptions` as an array with objects inside and have it set up like this because I need the questions with options to have a minimum of two and I'm sending it in the submit method like follows

```
questionOptions: [
    {
        option: ''
    },
    {
       option: ''
    },
],
```

```
submit() {
    this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$inertia.post(this.baseUrl, {
                question: this.form.question,
                survey_section_id: this.form.survey_section_id,
                response_type_id: this.form.response_type_id,
                optional: this.form.optional,
                questionOptions: this.form.questionOptions
            }).then(
                () => {
                    this.survey_question = this.$page.survey_question;
                    this.$message({
                       type: 'success',
                       message: 'Creado correctamente.'
                    });
                    this.loading = false
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                    this.loading = false;
                })
            } 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        this.reset();
    });
},
```

The reason I'm doing it like this is because some of the questions don't have these options, only about 1/4 have them as it depends on the response type selected. But it's not saving it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have not defined survey_question_id?

Comment: put the transaction in try and catch and in catch rollback the transaction. and for testing how about disabling the transaction?

Comment: @HamidAli I just caught that after struggling for a while, wish I had check this earlier! Thanks

Comment: Did you try using relationship insert: $preg-> SurveyQuestionOption()->create($options);